# Issue while running 2003 Access macro in 2010 using VB

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, scheduler

I was having VB exe program running using Task scheduler.

This Vb application is calling up the access macros and excel macro which was designed in Access 2003.

But after I have updated office from 2003 to 2010, the application is not running. The export part where I'm calling up the access macros is seems to be not working.

Even I have checked the trust center setting, Enabled the macro but even it is not yet running. The job keeps in Running state only.

But weird thing is that when I run the project, VB solution project instead of exe file through scheduler, everything is working fine. There I didn't get any issue. There macros of both Access and Excel are working.

When I debug the project, then everything works fine as it is supposed to be.

But when I create .exe and run using scheduler or directly run  the exe...the it just stops at the line where macro get called....

```
   Set objAccess = New Access.Application

   'Open the database and run the macro
    With objAccess
      .OpenCurrentDatabase strDB
      .DoCmd.RunMacro strMacro, lngRunX
```

I logged in the project at some places and found that, control just stops at .DoCmd.RunMacro strMacro, lngRunX and it also didn't give any error. It just stuck over there.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: When the scheduled job runs, are you logged in?

Comment: Under what user account does the scheduled task run?

Comment: Different user is configured in Scheduled task manager but I use my own ID while running the vb program on same machine.
It just work fine when it is my account but for other account id, it just stops while executing the macro.
why so??